# Display error message when user inputs "0", cannot get out of "error" message

Tags: java

Any idea on how I can fix this?  I'm telling the user to enter the amount of numbers he would like to average.  Of course as you can see in the code, if he inputs a 0 or a negative number I want it to flag the user to enter another number that is not 0 or a negative number.  The problem is, once the user puts a 0 or a negative number, it gets stuck in that state and I have to terminate the program.

Help?

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class TestProgTres 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
         //Variable Declaration
         String ShowSome;
         String ShowSomeAgain;
         int z           = 0;
         double avg      = 0;
         double totalamt = 0;

         ShowSome = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the amount of numbers you would like to average"); 
         double AllNumbers = Double.parseDouble(ShowSome);

         while (AllNumbers < 1)
         {
             JOptionPane.showInputDialog("You cannot enter a negative or a 0.  Enter the amount of numbers you would like to average");
             AllNumbers = Double.parseDouble(ShowSome);
         }//end while

             if (AllNumbers > 0)
             {
                 double Numbers [] = new double [(int) AllNumbers];

                 for (z = 0; z < Numbers.length; z++)
                 {
                     ShowSomeAgain= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter number " + (z + 1));
                     Numbers[z]=Double.parseDouble(ShowSomeAgain);

                     totalamt += Numbers[z];
                     avg = totalamt/AllNumbers;
                 }
             }

              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The  of the numberes entered is " + avg);
        }//end main
}// end class
```

Comment: You're not assigning to `ShowSome` and are ignoring the results from `JOptionPane.showInputDialog`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you want to ask the user at least once to enter a value, so why not just reduce the entire work load down to a single `do-while` loop, for example...

```
double AllNumbers = 0;
do {

    String ShowSome = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the amount of numbers you would like to average"); 
    AllNumbers = Double.parseDouble(ShowSome);
} while (AllNumbers < 1);
```

The main problem you're having with your current loop is you are ignoring the return value from the `JOptionPane` and continuously parsing what was previously entered...

```
// ShowSome is now set to, let's say 0...
ShowSome = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the amount of numbers you would like to average"); 
// AllNumbers  is now 0
double AllNumbers = Double.parseDouble(ShowSome);

while (AllNumbers < 1)
{
     // Prompting for a value, but you are ignoring it...
     JOptionPane.showInputDialog("You cannot enter a negative or a 0.  Enter the amount of numbers you would like to average");
     // Parsing ShowSome which is still 0 (as an example)...
     AllNumbers = Double.parseDouble(ShowSome);
 }//end while
```

Comment: any idea on how to ensure that a user doesn't input a decimal or a letter?  I want to make sure that what the user puts in is a whole number now that I am testing this program.

Comment: Quick question.  I just did this:

                 do 
         {
          try 
          {
           String ShowSome = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter numbers."); 
               AllNumbers = Integer.parseInt(ShowSome);
          } 
          catch(NumberFormatException e) 
          { 
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Value must be an integer!");
          }
         }


How do I make it so when the user clicks cancel, the error message doesn't pop up?

Comment: From memory, if the user presses cancel or closes the dialog via the [x] button, `JOptionPane` will return `null`...

Answer (score 3):

Well, it isn't the cleanest but this has a fairly important error,

```
ShowSome = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the amount of numbers "
    + "you would like to average"); 
double AllNumbers = Double.parseDouble(ShowSome);

while (AllNumbers < 1)
{
  JOptionPane.showInputDialog("You cannot enter a negative or a 0. "
      + "Enter the amount of numbers you would like to average");
  // HERE!
  AllNumbers = Double.parseDouble(ShowSome);
}//end while
```

You need to prompt for and update `ShowSome`.

```
while (AllNumbers < 1)
{
  // HERE!
  ShowSome = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("You cannot enter a negative or a 0. "
      + " Enter the amount of numbers you would like to average");
  // Get it again.
  AllNumbers = Double.parseDouble(ShowSome);
}//end while
```

Also, the Java naming convention would name your variables starting with a lower case letter. Using `showSome` would be easier to read `ShowSome` looks like a class name. Same with `allNumbers`.

Comment: As an alternative, a `do-while` loop might be a better structure to use, cause you want to do at least one iteration of the loop...just saying ... and why are you sowing the input dialog twice?

Comment: Know that feeling, looks better now +1

Answer (score 2):

Move following code inside the loop to prompt for input every time when user enters wrong input and break loop while you get what you want.

```
     //Declare ShowSome and AllNumbers outside loop
     while (true){
          try{
            ShowSome = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter....."); 
            AllNumbers = Double.parseDouble(ShowSome);
            //May Throw exception for invalid input So be careful with this 
            if(AllNumbers>=1)break;
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog("You cannot enter a negative or a 0"); 
          }catch(NumberFormatException e){
          JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Not a valid Number!"); 
          //Not Recommended to swallow the exception
          }
     }
```

Secondly there is no meaning of checking `if (AllNumbers > 0)` after doing this as above code will prompt until user enters wrong input so you will definitely get proper value which is `>=1`.

You should use `try-catch` mechanism to avoid `Exception` for invalid input.

Moreover you should declare `AllNumbers` as `integer` to avoid cast.